GoLang goWSL hide CMD window when command is run
I am working on GoLang UI application on Windows that uses the awesome Fyne and GoWSL (https://github.com/ubuntu/GoWSL) packages to run WSL commands from my UI.
I have a function that calls WSL. It works well, however it opens an ugly CMD window each time I run a command. Ideally, I would like to run these WSL commands in the background without them being visible to the user.
Here is my function:
func runWSLCommand(command string) error {

    // Get the default distribution
    distro, ok, distroErr := wsl.DefaultDistro(context.Background())
    if distroErr != nil {
       panic(distroErr)
    }
    if !ok {
       panic(distroErr)
    }

    // Getting config and printing it
    pp.Println("Printing distro information:")
    pp.Printf("%v\n", distro)

    // Showing CombinedOutput
    pp.Println("Running a command with redirected output: " + command)

    // Get the command
    cmd := distro.Command(context.Background(), command)

    // Ensure to hide the window
    //cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}

    // Run wsl command and get output
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
       errorPrinter.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected error: %v\nError message: %s", err, out))
       return errors.New("Error: Failed to run command: " + fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected error: %v\nError message: %s", err, out))
    } else {
       pp.Println("WSL: " + string(out))
       return nil
    }

}

I have tried googling and hiding the window with the following solution. However, the code will not compile with the hidden window flag uncommented:
// Get the command
cmd := distro.Command(context.Background(), command)

// Ensure to hide the window
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true} // This fails to compile

// Run wsl command and get output
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unexpected error: %v\nError message: %s", err, out)
    return errors.New("Error: Failed to run command: " + fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected error: %v\nError message: %s", err, out))
} else {
    pp.Println("WSL: " + string(out))
    return nil
}

How can I call the GoWSL library without opening a new CMD window for each command? Thanks.

When something doesn’t compile it is helpful to share the error. That should work but it will only work on Windows - so if you are compiling it in WSL (Linux) that could be the problem.
Working on an emulation of one system in another will make things like this more problematic and I recommend you compile the windows app on a windows environment instead - cmd or even the MSYS2 setup recommended in the Fyne getting started guide. https://fyne.io/started

Thanks for the comment. The compilation error is "cmd.SysProcAttr undefined (type *gowsl.Cmd has no field or method SysPRocAttr)"
